# Node.js - To Load All Files, or Not To Load All Files, that is my question

Tags: javascript, node.js, autoload

I am a life long LAMP developer and and am use to using autoloader to load classes when I want them, but not until then, but now learning Node.js. Many examples show index.js files within a folder that loads all the files.

For instance:
Model

```
--- CarModel.js

--- TruckModel.js

--- MotorcylceModel.js

--- index.js - this file includes all the models in the folder.
```

In my code I use

```
  const {CarModel} = require('./index');
```

Is this the preferred method?

If so, why?

Why not use an autoloader and only load files when they are needed?

I am searching online, but not finding anything that clearly explains this. If you have an article that would help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The essence of the index file is to export all of your model all at once while still scaling and updating them individually.
This is a common practice in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use an autoloader because there isn't one - entirely unlike in PHP. In PHP, there is a global symbol table - a class name means something, regardless of where it's used. So, if you call a class CarModel, that name can be referenced globally. When you refer to it by name, the autoloader can locate the file. This is aided by PSR-4 (Autoloader), which specifies where to find a class file based on its namespace and name.

In JavaScript, this is not so. There *is* a global object (`global` in Node.js, `window` in browsers), but the constructs - functions, classes, etc. - are not global and have nothing to do with it. When you `require()` a file with a class implementation, for example, you're really creating a variable that contains that file's `exports` value. So:

- No namespaces
- No global or qualified names for classes and functions

There's also a counter-argument: why would you lazy-load files if you can preload? Unlike PHP applications, Node.js processes are usually long-running, so the start-up phase can take as much as it needs - because then you end up using the already-loaded code all the time, instead of making expensive filesystem calls if a user tries to do something new.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies things. This is like .NET, where everything is loaded in memory so things are faster as you use the app.